# Loading image from URL on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have no idea why this isn't working.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:place.iconData];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[imageView setImage:image];
```

imageView is an IBOutlet hooked up through IB. place.iconData is http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png. For some reason, though, it won't load. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Remember that loading an image using this method loads synchronously and will block your view controller while the image is loading over network, which will typically be a very noticeable delay. Consider using NSURLConnecion

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading about that, but I don't quite understand. Is there a link or example that's really clear that you know of, so I can implement that better?

Comment: This link seems ok. http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/ . Note that he limits image size to 2K.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working either...any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your data being freed before it got assigned?

Maybe try manually allocating memory for the NSData:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:place.iconData];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[imageView setImage:image];

[data release];
[image release];
```

Comment: No, it isn't. In the end I gave up on IB and programatically created the UIImageview, and it worked fine. Go figure.

Comment: Can't go wrong with coding over using Interface Builder :P Sometimes when you move things around in Interface Builder, it breaks the connection between views and controllers. Perhaps your view controller's UIImageView object connection is broken? :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[imageView setImage:image]; 
//or imageView.Image=image;
```

Comment: That should work, try it with a different image URL. Otherwise check your views and that you don't have any nil values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NSURL. Follow this url http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/download-and-create-an-image-from-a-url.html