# iPhone NSMutableArray loading background image from url

Tags: iphone, image, url, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray where it stores url to a image. And this NSMutableArray is called userPic. From my server it only prints out the url: not JSON or anything, only the url.

I can see in the output in Xcode that it shows the url, but how to I get this url in userPic to a background? Im trying to addSubView with the image for a background.

If something is unclear, sorry about that. Just let me know.

Comment: using [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] you can get image data from url and then need to assign to .image property ot UIImageView

Comment: Thanks for answer, but could you give me an example? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811640/loading-image-from-url-on-iphone  May this help you.

Comment: Put your relevant code here ..

Comment: You wanna set image on your background view(subview) ?

Comment: Yes, it will just be a showing profile picture type

Comment: See my code...I've added image on "newView".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use this one.And i  think your `URL` at index 0 of your array.

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[userPic objectAtIndex:0]]; // put your particular index where your image url in your array...
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData];

[newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img]]
```

Comment: Im trying your code now, Im not getting any errors. So thanks :)

Comment: Can´t sorry. Need more reputation.